# Compilation error combining three Either methods

Tags: scala

Given these three methods that return `Future[Either[String,Int]]`:

```
def greater(x:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
  if (x>0)
      Right(x)
  else
      Left("Is not greater")
}

def less(x:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
  if (x<0)
      Right(x)
  else
      Left("Is not less")
}

def zero(x:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
  if (x==0)
      Right(x)
  else
      Left("Is not zero")
}
```

The following method that invokes the three above throws a compilation error:

```
def evaluate(x:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = {
   val future = greater(x)
   future.flatMap { either =>
       either.right.flatMap { response => // <-- error in this line
           val future2 = less(response)
           future2.map { either2 =>   
             either2.right.map { response2 => zero(response2) }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

The error:

> type mismatch; found : scala.util.Either[String,Nothing] required:
>   scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String,Int]]

How to fix the `evaluate` method?

Comment: So what is `evaluate` supposed to return after the future is done? For `-1` is will be `Left("Is not greater")`, doesn't look like something useful. Or was it supposed to be another way round?

Comment: Is not useful, it's just an example to ask for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Classic case of Monad transformers.*

Use `EitherT` from cats

```
val result =
  for {
    a <- EitherT(greater(x))
    b <- EitherT(less(a))
    c <- EitherT(zero(b))
  } yield c
```

final value: `result.value`

Why EitherT?

`Either` is inside the another seemingly monad `Future`. So, `EitherT` can be used.